# How to have the scroll functionality in a Bootstrap modal opened from another modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently having two buttons inside a Bootstrap Modal:

```
<button type="button" class="left_portfolio_item portfolio_controls"></button>
<button id="to_modal_two" type="button" class="right_portfolio_item portfolio_controls"></button>
```

The second one with the id `to_modal_two`, when clicked, should close the first modal (the one in which he is) and open a second one.
To achieve this I am using jQuery:

```
$('#to_modal_two').click(function() {
    $('#modal_one').modal('hide');
    $('#modal_two').modal('show');
});
```

The first modal is closing then the second one is opening but unfortunetally I can't use the scroll functionality inside it.
Is there any work-arounds to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: its a button not a text area

Comment: @mahendrapratapjewaria I am not asking how to have the scroll inside the button, but inside a modal.

Comment: And easy solution might be to use a setTimeout on the modal('show'), there is also the events on the modal to detect when the modal form has totally closed.

Comment: @Keith I will try this now and see how it goes.

Comment: Hi, when you open modal after another modal, your page body element will have one modal class, remove it once you open the second modal, it should resolve your issue.

Comment: @thedarkcoder Thank you for you reply. Actually it didn't work with just removing the body class, I had to remove one from the first modal aswell and for some unkown reason using this instead of hiding it with `.modal('hide')` fix the scroll functionality on the second modal.

Comment: Have you tried destroying first modal??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've tried to make it work like I've intended:

```
$('#to_modal_two').click(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('body').css("padding-right","");
    $('#modal_one').removeClass('in');
    $('#modal_one').css("display","");
    $('#modal_one').attr("aria-hidden","true");
    $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
    $('#modal_two').modal('show');
});
```

One bug which I haven't yet figure it out how to fix it is that after I close the second modal to access the first using "the normal way" (`<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_one"></button>`) I have to do 2 or 3 clicks before it opens the modal.